# Multi-class clasification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Just getting my toes wet with running some models on the Iris dataset and was wondering if using One-vs-Rest is required or not? Because I can fit a linear model without it, but using OVR yields different results.

Any explainations would be great, thank you!

[image: Code screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear regression is not a classification technique. Most of this is meaningless as a result. Did you mean logistic regression? You do not need OneVsRestClassifier explicitly if you set LogisticRegression to handle multi-class classification internally with 'ovr' (one vs rest again) or 'multinomial' (softmax loss)

Comment: Thanks @Sean Owen